# How do I verify the integrity of my local chainblock data?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, storage

If I suspect local data corruption, is there a way to verify that my blockchain data is valid and will not affect my Ethereum work and transactions?

Example: I switched to a self-compiled version of geth and changed parameters after about 30GB of downloading.  I see a .log file where I would expect a .ldb file.  Another example would be if a hard drive is beginning to show data corruption.